# Android Webview Google Charts not working

Tags: android, webview, google-visualization

I have been searching the internet and SO for a solution embedding a WebView displaying a webpage with google-charts. This far i have found nothing. I do not want use the image API nor building the html, as I can't access the needed data for rendering the chart.

Any suggestions?

Stacktrace:

```
    09-29 12:26:34.158  29906-29906/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.MMStatisticsActivity.onCreateView(MMStatisticsActivity.java:32)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code:

```
public class MMScheduleActivity extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_schedule, container, false);
        WebView browser = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.schedule_webview);

        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
        int event_id = Integer.parseInt(sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.event_id), "0"));

        if(event_id!=0){
            String url = "http://xxxxxx/page/stats/" + event_id + '/';
            Log.i("URL", url);
            browser.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Worth mentioning is that I load the WebView within a Fragment.

Comment: Null Pointer on MMStatisticsActivity.java:32. What's that line? Also, add relevant code.

Comment: What's line number 32?

Comment: WebView browser = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.schedule_webview); The WebView-id is there.

Comment: ok.. debug and see if `view` is null. May be some error in inflating.

Comment: What points? Is issue resolved?

Comment: Yup, it is. Thanks for pointing out my stupidity! :)

Comment: So how do we give you the 50 points?

Comment: I think you will need to wait till tomorrow. As [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) it says: Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have shown a google chart in WebView, and didn't find it that difficult.

Snippets for your html file:

```
//include google api js file
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

//a div for chart
<div id="my-chart">
</div>
```

Snippets from js file:

```
// In case there is no network
// the google jsapi is not loaded causing the screen to go white and break the application
// Check if google object is not null
if(typeof(google) !== 'undefined')
{
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
}

//a separate function for drawing data. Just call it wherever you need to redraw the chart
function drawChart(chartData){
    data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Col1');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Col2');

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        ideasChart.data.addRow("data1", "data2");
    }

    chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('my-chart'));
    chart.draw(data, chartOptions);
}

//chartOptions to customize your chart, its text color, etc.

chartOptions = {
    chartType:"ComboChart",
    containerId:"visualization",
    stackSeries: true,
    isStacked : true,
    backgroundColor: '#242424',
    legend: 'none',
    tooltip:{
        trigger:'none'
    },
    enableInteractivity: false,
    colors : ['#6DB1E2','#FDCB34'],
    chartArea: {
        backgroundColor: {
            stroke: '#fff',
            strokeWidth: 1
        }
    },
    seriesDefaults: {

        rendererOptions: {
            barPadding: 0,
            barMargin: 10
        },
    },

    seriesType: "bars",     
    bar:
    {
        groupWidth:"80%"
    },

    viewWindowMode : {
        max: 'pretty'
    }
};
```

And in your android WebView,

you would need to load your html file as:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Hope it helps. You would need to customize your chartOptions as per your requirement. And refer [examples](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples) to start it.

**EDIT:**

If you have a URL which shows google charts, then you would simply need to add

```
myWebView.loadUrl(strLink);
```

in your Activity.

Comment: Your solution implicates that I have the data needed for rendering the graphs, which I do not. My question says that this is not the kind of solution I want. Anyhoot, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @TompaLompa so where is the data that you need? in native android? and you want that in js?

Comment: @TompaLompa and you need to show that webpage in your webview? Then can't you use `myWebView.loadUrl(strLink);`? where strLink will be your webpage url?

Comment: Tried that, crashed the application

Comment: can we give animations to it ?