# Xamarin forms webview not showing chart data in my device

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

I have used WebView for showing data using URL but my chart view is not loading in webview, I also give all below permission for webview.

[image]

```
Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
Control.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
Control.Settings.DatabaseEnabled = true;
Control.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
Control.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
Control.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;
Control.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
Control.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
Control.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = true;
Control.SetWebViewClient(new WebClient(this));

 class WebClient : WebViewClient
        {
            WebViewRendererForAndroid _renderer;
            public WebClient(WebViewRendererForAndroid renderer)
            {
                _renderer = renderer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("renderer");
            }
            public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(AWebView view, string url)
            {
                try
                {
                    var Token = UserSettings.AccesToken;
                    Dictionary<String, String> headers = new Dictionary<String, String>();
                    headers.Add("Authorization", Token);
                    view.LoadUrl(url, headers);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
                return true;
            }
            public override void OnReceivedError(AWebView view, IWebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error)
            {
                base.OnReceivedError(view, request, error);
            }
            public override void OnReceivedHttpError(AWebView view, IWebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse)
            {
                base.OnReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
                var source = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = request.Url.ToString() };
                var args = new WebNavigatedEventArgs(WebNavigationEvent.NewPage, source, request.Url.ToString(), WebNavigationResult.Failure);
                _renderer.ElementController.SendNavigated(args);
            }
            public override void OnReceivedError(AWebView view, [GeneratedEnum] ClientError errorCode, string description, string failingUrl)
            {
                base.OnReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                var source = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = failingUrl };
                var args = new WebNavigatedEventArgs(WebNavigationEvent.NewPage, source, failingUrl, WebNavigationResult.Failure);
                _renderer.ElementController.SendNavigated(args);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Does the chat data show in a browser?

Comment: yes, All data show/load in browser but not show/load in webview.

Comment: Can you give me a link for test?

Comment: sorry, not possible

Comment: OK, then it's hard for me to reproduce the issue on my side.

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038220/android-webview-google-charts-not-working

Answer (score 0):

I have solved these issues using javascript, we have to inject javascript function after page load finished like this.

```
public override void OnPageFinished(AWebView view, string url)
{
   base.OnPageFinished(view, url);

   view.LoadUrl("javascript:(loadData('" + Token + "'))");
}
```